# SharePoint custom templates doesn't appear on word online (on word app works fine)

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365, word, asset-library

I am new in SharePoint-365 and I need your help.

I have created a document library on my SharePoint with custom word templates.

With this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/organization-assets-library) make the list as organization asset library and I have added some .dotx file like the image bellow

[image]

When I open word app on my computer and click 'More Templates' button I can see them and can create a new document based on the templates (Works fine!)

[image]

The problem is with the online word, because I cannot find them and I want the same functionality, how can make the templates visible on word online?

[image]

---

**UPDATE**:

With the helpful answer of the Kalpesh Vaghela, still unable to see the templates although we have license E3:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By default it will not be available in particular Office App but it will be in Create Menu of the Office.com

[image]

Official Documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/organization-assets-library

> When a user selects to create a new Office file (from Office.com or the Word, Excel, or PowerPoint desktop app), the user can select the tab for your organization to see the templates. (To use this feature on Office.com, users need to be assigned a license to Office 365 E3 or E5. The templates aren't available from the New menu. To create a doc from a template, go to Office.com > app start page > Office Template Library.)

Reference Link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/125512/organisation-assets-library-cannot-be-found-in-wor.html

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Comment: yes it was helpful, but although that we have E3 license still not able to see the templates, check my updated question

Comment: You need to click on your Organization library tab which you have blurred in your screen shot and inside that you should see templates as it works fine for me.

Comment: Same issue here. Looks like this feature does not work well in Office Web version. 
For us even Word templates also show up under PowerPoint Web version. 
@KalpeshVaghela - yes we do see Org templates from your steps you mentioned above but only PowerPoint templates there, no Word templates. 
Anyone has any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

Same here with Organization assets library setup in SharePoint

Office clients

- PowerPoint templates appear
- Word Templates appear
  Office Online:
- PowerPoint templates appear
- Word Templates do NOT appear